# Why does Windows 10 Task Manager say that my LaCie 750GB Rikki external hard drive's capacity is 4.5 TB?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, task-manager

Windows 10 Task Manager say that my LaCie 750GB Rikki external hard drive's capacity is 4.5 TB. See below. Why?

[image]

[image]

Disk management confirms that the LaCie 750GB Rikki external hard drive is 750 GB, i.e. ~698 GiB (disk 1 in the screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: Likely has something to do with the unallocated partition  and the 10MB partition, or a simpler explanation, the drive firmware is at fault. What does file explorer indicate the size of the drive is?